# Is the pythagoras theorem true for an infinite set of vectors?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Consider a collection of orthogonal vectors $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{k}$. We know that $$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^{k}x_n\right\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{k}\|x_n\|^2$$

Now consider an infinite collection of orthogonal vectors $\{y_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}.$ Is it true that 
$$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_n\right\|^2=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|y_n\|^2$$

Comment: You have to assume that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty y_n$ converges in $H$ (which is equivalent to the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \|y_n\|^2$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\left\|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_n\right\|^2 &=\left\langle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_n,\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}y_k\right\rangle\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\langle y_n,y_k\right\rangle\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\langle y_n,y_k\right\rangle\delta_{k,n}\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\langle y_n,y_n\right\rangle\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\|y_n\|^2.
\end{align}

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that continuity of inner product is used implicitly.

Comment: @CheeHan: Absolutely worthwhile mentioning. Thank you.